# For 2L of final cider do I need to put the whole yeast sachet?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, cider

I have only 4kg of apples, which will give me 2L of cider. I'm using an 11g dry yeast sachet. Do I need to pour the whole 11g or just 5g?

If I use it all, will the final taste be influenced by the yeast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be ok just using less than an 1/8th of it, but wouldn't do harm adding the whole pack.

Just follow the pitching instructions on the yeasts datasheet. Hydration etc.